# how to autoplay with this slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I have this slideshow. You can see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/handoi912/Yh6Lp/

Now, I want slideshow autoplay, i can't. Please help me! Thanks!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#cn-slideshow').slideshow();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the slideshow from (what script are you using)? You should separate your JavaScript and HTML in your jsfiddle; the left bottom quadrant is for JavaScript, top left is for HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), to trigger the click event of the next button. You can keep the original slideshow intact that way.

You would run this on document ready:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('.cn-nav-next').trigger('click');}, 
3000);
```

You can see it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/burnsjeremy/SrkzD/

Edit:
My first answer was bothering me a little so I updated it to separate out some code. I also added a mouseover to stop the auto-play feature until mouseout. You can see that in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/burnsjeremy/pHrvJ/

Code from edit that will make the slideshow stop so users can flip through slideshow like normal.

```
var intervalStart = setInterval(function () {
    $('.cn-nav-next').trigger('click');
},
3000);
// Stop slideshow on mouseover, and mouseout start back
$('#cn-slideshow').mouseover(function(){
    clearInterval(intervalStart);
}).mouseout(function(){
    intervalStart = setInterval(function(){
        $('.cn-nav-next').trigger('click');
    }, 3000) ;
})
```

This should be plenty to get you started on solving this problem with ease. Thanks!

Comment: thanks! Sorry because I don't have permison vote for you! :( p/s: My english not good :((

Comment: Although this works to start the slideshow on page load, it prevents normal slideshow behavior so I don't think it's the best solution.  For example, if a user hits the previous button we could reasonably assume they either want to move in that direction (previous), or move one and not move further - this would make it move forward.  Most slideshow plugins that I've come across have an autoplay feature (or timeout, or some other name) that takes that behavior into account.  I think the best solution is to find out the plugin that is being used, and see if it offers that option.

Comment: I don't understand, I added an edit fiddle that stops the slideshow on mouseover so it doesn't interfere with user interaction (only tested on chrome but should work on most browsers) and starts it back when they mouseout. Are you saying that it should start back and go in the direction the user was flipping through the pictures? I went through the slideshow code and there was no auto-play, although it can be extended to have auto-play I don't think that was in scope for this question.

Comment: I posted that comment before you edited the post or the fiddle. I haven't been able to look at the updated code

Comment: oh ok, I had realized that I was a little to quick on my first answer so I edited it with a little more info. Yes the first code block answers the question but it also was not the best answer. Thanks for the input!!!

Comment: And @AnhTuấn I would highly recommend trying to use different slider plugin like [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/). (Yes my answer works but it is just a quick hack in reality, something like cycle2 is a sustainable solution.) It offers great functionality and you could style it to look just like the slider that is mentioned above. The transitions and animations on the next/prev would be the only tricky part but can easily be accomplished. It would also give you some great experience in using jQuery plugins in your sites.